# Add / remove input field dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to use jquery to build a dynamic add/ remove form.
IT should look like:

Name Type Required?

The example input :

- Name Type Required?
- Tony  Admin  checked (checkbox) Delete <==press the button will delete the row

What i have got is a example of add/ remove input box how can it  convert to my idea? Do i have to use multi coloumn table? Thank you for kindly help

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>jQuery add / remove textbox example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    div{
        padding:8px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>jQuery add / remove textbox example</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });

     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

    var msg = '';
    for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
    }
          alert(msg);
     });
  });
</script>
</head><body>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I took the liberty of putting together a jsFiddle illustrating the functionality of building a custom form using jQuery. [Here it is...](http://jsfiddle.net/qBURS/1824/)

EDIT: Updated the jsFiddle to include remove buttons for each field.

EDIT: As per the request in the last comment, code from the jsFiddle is below.

EDIT: As per Abhishek's comment, I have updated the jsFiddle (and code below) to cater for scenarios where duplicate field IDs might arise.

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset id="buildyourform">
    <legend>Build your own form!</legend>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Preview form" class="add" id="preview" />
<input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
        var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
        var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" />");
        var fType = $("<select class=\"fieldtype\"><option value=\"checkbox\">Checked</option><option value=\"textbox\">Text</option><option value=\"textarea\">Paragraph</option></select>");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fName);
        fieldWrapper.append(fType);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });
    $("#preview").click(function() {
        $("#yourform").remove();
        var fieldSet = $("<fieldset id=\"yourform\"><legend>Your Form</legend></fieldset>");
        $("#buildyourform div").each(function() {
            var id = "input" + $(this).attr("id").replace("field","");
            var label = $("<label for=\"" + id + "\">" + $(this).find("input.fieldname").first().val() + "</label>");
            var input;
            switch ($(this).find("select.fieldtype").first().val()) {
                case "checkbox":
                    input = $("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\" />");
                    break;
                case "textbox":
                    input = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\" />");
                    break;
                case "textarea":
                    input = $("<textarea id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\" ></textarea>");
                    break;    
            }
            fieldSet.append(label);
            fieldSet.append(input);
        });
        $("body").append(fieldSet);
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
body
{
    font-family:Gill Sans MT;
    padding:10px;
}
fieldset
{
    border: solid 1px #000;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    margin:5px 0px;
}
legend
{
    padding:0px 10px;
    background:black;
    color:#FFF;
}
input.add
{
    float:right;
}
input.fieldname
{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
}
select.fieldtype
{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
}
input.remove
{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
}
#yourform label
{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
}
#yourform input, #yourform textarea
{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: The delete function is exactly what i want , i am trying to modify your code to add one more field in each row

Comment: It seems that i don't have to modify the jquery script , just add an input element .

Comment: I wounder  what is the name of the second one, given that there are two textbox in the same row

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? There's an input (textbox) for the field name (i.e. label) and a dropdown for the field type.

Comment: What is the id (what i can call to capture the data) of each input field ?

Comment: How is it complicated? Should I add some comments in the JS code to explain what's going on?

Comment: If you add 2 fields and then remove 1st, and then add 1 more field again, there will  be 2 elments with same ID, how to solve that?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey you are indeed correct. I have updated the jsFiddle (and code sample in the answer) to cater for such scenarios. Good on you for pointing it out almost 6 years later!

Comment: Hehe, you shoud be proud, even after 6years your answer is still helping people. btw I had same issue of generating same ID twice.

Answer (score 46):

You need to create the element.

```
input = jQuery('<input name="myname">');
```

and then append it to the form.

```
jQuery('#formID').append(input);
```

to remove an input you use the remove functionality.

```
jQuery('#inputid').remove();
```

This is the basic idea, you may have feildsets that you append it too instead, or maybe append it after a specific element, but this is how to build anything dynamically really.

Comment: Then , $("#TextBoxDiv" + rowID).remove(); is for remove?

Answer (score 16):

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

HTML CODE

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you explain how to populate an existing string list as well?

Comment: wow , very good answer , you are amazing!, thanks .

Comment: I adapted to `var max_fields      = 6;
    var wrapper         = $(".input-fields-wrap");
    var add_button      = $(".add-field-button");
    var fields       = $(".input-fields-c");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
   $(fields).clone(true, true).append('<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(wrapper);
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })`

Answer (score 7):

you can do it as follow:

```
 $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });
```

refer live demo http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/

Answer (score 7):

Here is a sample HTML & JS code

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
    let template = `<div class='item'><input type="text" name="items[]" placeholder="Enter Something" /><button class="remove">X</button></div>`; 

    $("#add").on("click", ()=>{
        $("#items").append(template);
    })
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", (e)=>{
        $(e.target).parent("div").remove();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class='item'>
   <input type="text" name="items[]" placeholder="Enter Something">
   <button id="add">Add +</button>
</div>
<div id="items"></div>
```

For detailed tutorial https://geekvortex.com/jquery-add-remove-input-fields

Comment: Almost 5 years later and this worked great for me, thank you.

Comment: The tutorial link has been broken.

Comment: Tutorial Link has been changed now, it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Weyb/1/) with corrected line breaks, or see it below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var MaxInputs       = 2; //maximum extra input boxes allowed
var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

//on add input button click
$(AddButton).click(function (e) {
        //max input box allowed
        if(x <= MaxInputs) {
            FieldCount++; //text box added ncrement
            //add input box
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_'+ FieldCount +'"/> <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a></div>');
            x++; //text box increment

            $("#AddMoreFileId").show();

            $('AddMoreFileBox').html("Add field");

            // Delete the "add"-link if there is 3 fields.
            if(x == 3) {
                $("#AddMoreFileId").hide();
                $("#lineBreak").html("<br>");
            }
        }
        return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        if( x > 1 ) {
                $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
                x--; //decrement textbox

                $("#AddMoreFileId").show();

                $("#lineBreak").html("");

                // Adds the "add" link again when a field is removed.
                $('AddMoreFileBox').html("Add field");
        }
    return false;
}) 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

why not remove the `.after()` in the line

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
```

to

```
newTextBoxDiv.html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
```

Answer (score 1):

In your click function, you can write:

```
function addMoreRows(frm) {
   rowCount ++;
   var recRow = '<p id="rowCount'+rowCount+'"><tr><td><input name="" type="text" size="17%"  maxlength="120" /></td><td><input name="" type="text"  maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 5px 0 5px;"/></td><td><input name="" type="text" maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 10px 0 0px;"/></td></tr> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeRow('+rowCount+');">Delete</a></p>';
   jQuery('#addedRows').append(recRow);
}
```

Or follow this link:
http://www.discussdesk.com/add-remove-more-rows-dynamically-using-jquery.htm

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be:

```
<script>
$(document)
        .ready(
                function() {
                    var wrapper = $(".myFields");
                    $(add_button)
                            .click(
                                    function(e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        $(wrapper)
                                                .append(
                                                        '.....'); //add fields here
                                    });
                    $(wrapper).on("click", ".delFld", function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).parent('div').remove();
                    })
                }); 
</script>
```

Source: [Here](https://github.com/ajkr195/dynamicFormPopulationJQuery/blob/master/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Add / Remove Table Rows Dynamically</title>
<style type="text/css">
    form{
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    form input, button{
        padding: 5px;
    }
    table{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table, th, td{
        border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    }
    table th, table td{
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add-row").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup);
        });

        // Find and remove selected table rows
        $(".delete-row").click(function(){
            $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });    
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
    </form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td>
                <td>Peter Parker</td>
                <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You should be able to create and remove input field dynamically by using jquery using this method(https://www.adminspress.com/onex/view/uaomui), Even you can able to generate input fields in bulk and export to string.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="image" id="input-image{{ image_row }}" />

inputt= '<input type="hidden" name="product_image' value="somevalue">

$("#input-image"+row).remove().append(inputt);
```