# How to pass textbox value which has the data to spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC controller in one of my project.

Below is my JSP code in which it will show three radio button. One is `Insert`, second radio button is `Update` and third radio button is `Delete`.

Once I click `Insert` radio button, it show two text box next to Insert radio button, and same thing with other two radio button as well -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doDisplay(radio) {
    switch (radio.value) {
    case "Insert":
        document.getElementById("inserts").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("updates").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("delete").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("dynamicName").value = "insert";
        break;
    case "Update":
        document.getElementById("inserts").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("updates").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("delete").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("dynamicName").value = "update";
        break;
    case "Delete":
        document.getElementById("inserts").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("updates").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("delete").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("dynamicName").value = "delete";
        break;
    }
}
</script>

<body>

  <form method="post" action="testOperation">
  <!-- I used only one hidden box to store value -->
  <input type="hidden" name="name" id="dynamicName">

    <input type="radio" name="tt" value="Insert"
        onclick="doDisplay(this);" /> Insert <span id="inserts"
        style="display: none"> <label for="Node"> Node </label> <input
        type="text" name="node" size="20" /> <label for="Data"> Data </label>
        <input type="text" name="data" size="100" />

    </span> <br /> <input type="radio" name="tt" value="Update"
        onclick="doDisplay(this);" /> Update <span id="updates"
        style="display: none"> <label for="Node"> Node </label> <input
        type="text" name="node" size="20" /> <label for="Data"> Data </label>
        <input type="text" name="data" size="100"/>

    </span> <br /> <input type="radio" name="tt" value="Delete"
        onclick="doDisplay(this);" /> Delete <span id="delete"
        style="display: none"> <label for="Node"> Node </label> <input
        type="text" name="node" size="20" /> <label for="Data"> Data </label>
        <input type="text" name="data" size="100"/>

    </span> <br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Below is Controller code -

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, String> testOperation() {
        final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, String> testOperations(@RequestParam String name, 
                                              @RequestParam String node, 
                                              @RequestParam String data) {
        final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(node);
        System.out.println(data);

        return model;
    }
```

Suppose I click `Insert` radio button and type `Hello` in the first text and `World` in the second text box, then I will hit the submit button, and after that I am seeing `insert` value in the `name`  variable which is good but `hello,,` value in the `node` variable and `world,,` value in the `data` variable which I don't want.

And same thing with update and delete.

Is there any way to avoid this? Meaning I would like to see only `hello` value in the node variable and `world` value in the `data` variable instead of being separated by comma.?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think this is because there are 3 input text boxes with name="node" and 3 input text boxes with name="data", can you reuse the "node" and "data" text boxes for insert, update and delete, so that there is just 1 of each? and show/hide just the radio button in the javascript?

Comment: @indybee: That's a good point but how will this work? I need to show two textboxes whenever I am clicking insert, update or delete radion button? Will this work still? Can you provide an example for this if possible?

Comment: on click, instead of showing-hiding, try adding-removing from DOM

Comment: @arahant: I am not sure how to do that? Can you provide an example for the same if possible basis on my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking radio buttons you just hide fields for user, but params are still visible and send via POST request. In spring params with that same names are seen as an array. If you dont want to send multiply params with that same name you should not only hide input but remove it calling following code from jquery

```
$('#input-id').remove();
```

Remember that you have also to service adding fields by clicking radio buttons. I found an example how to to it:
http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/ 
More info you can find also here [Add / remove input field dynamically with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173182/add-remove-input-field-dynamically-with-jquery)

EDIT
According to your comment i recomend you to use this code http://jsfiddle.net/tFLnd/ 
It is much more shorter, maybe not the best one because i wrote it just now but do the job
 Of course you have to add jQuery to your page to use this code

Comment: Thanks shark. What change should I make in my code base.? Any idea?

Comment: I can also see that there is always that same input added:) maybe just show it always and send additional parameter as you do in fact. There is no reason for hiding that same inputs

Comment: :Sorry for replying so late.. Thanks a lot for the help. Yes it works fine for `node` and `data` variable as shown in the my above code in the question in `testOperations` method.. But the value in the `name` variable is coming as empty.. Instead of that, it should show `insert` if I am clicking `insert radio button` or it should show `update` if I am clicking `update radio button` and same with delete.. Any idea how we can fix this?