# Add input field with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm quite new to jQuery, so still trying to wrap my head around how it works.

I'm creating a admin-panel where the admin can insert some questions. As its not a fixed amount, the admin should be able to add or remove extra input-fields, so the admin can choose the desired amount questions.

This is how it looks graphically: [image: Add-remove]

And this is the code:

```
            <div class="adinputfield90">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Insert question 1"> <span class="font-entypo icon-circled-cross adaddnextremove" aria-hidden="true"></span></input>
            </div>
```

The span class holds the image, so the add-new input is just another webfont.

How can I get this to work, so I can add an infinite amounts of inputfields? I should of cause make sure that if theres only one input I can only add, and not remove that one.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add / remove input field dynamically with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173182/add-remove-input-field-dynamically-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Include this in head section of the page

```
<script>
$(function(){

  $('.adinputfield90 span').click(addTextBox);

});

function addTextBox(){
  $('.adinputfield90').append('<input type="text" placeholder="Insert question 1"> <span class="font-entypo icon-circled-cross adaddnextremove" aria-hidden="true"></span></input>');
  $('.adinputfield90 span').unbind('click');
  $('.adinputfield90 span').click(addTextBox);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var template='<div class="adinputfield90">';
 template=template+'<input type="text" placeholder="Insert question 1"> 
 <span class="font-entypo icon-circled-cross adaddnextremove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </input>';
  template=template+'</div>'


  $("#htmlContainerId").append(template);
```

htmlContainerId - The container into which we are inserting the content.That will be the element just outside of  'adinputfield90' ie, the container of 'adinputfield90'

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('.adaddnextremove').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().clone(true).appendTo('body');
    $('.remove').show();
    $('.adaddnextremove').hide();
    $('.adinputfield90').last().find('.remove').hide();
    $('.adinputfield90').last().find('.adaddnextremove').show();
});
$('.remove').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FX896/)</kbd>