# Adding PHP session values to dynamic form fields

Tags: php, jquery, forms, session, dynamic

I am using the following code which allows users to click on the "Add Button" to add more text box fields.

My form field is supposed to have PHP session values so that when users fill in values that are not allowed, they will be brought back to the form page with the session values that they have filled in previously. However, I have tried and the session values do not appear. Any advise?

```
<?php
 session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery add / remove textbox example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  div{
    padding:8px;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>jQuery add / remove textbox example</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {

       if(counter>5){
            alert("Only 5 textboxes are allowed.");
            return false;
       }   

     var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox_' + counter + 
      '" id="textbox_' + counter + '" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION["textbox_' + counter + '"])){print $_SESSION["textbox_' + counter + '"];} ?>" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


   counter++;
 });

 $("#removeButton").click(function () {
  if(counter==1){
      alert("No more textbox to remove");
      return false;
   }   

   counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

    });

     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

             var msg = '';
             for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
                msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
             }
           alert(msg);
        });
     });
   </script>
</head><body>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
     <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
          <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='textbox' name='textbox1' id='textbox1' value='<?php if(isset($_SESSION["textbox1"])){print $_SESSION["textbox1"];}?>'>
     </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you storing values in session? You need to store $_POST in $_SESSION in your server side script that is receiving data from form.

Comment: Actually I dont see a `<form>` tag or any AJAX so this code is not even being submitted to the server for processing

Comment: `jquery-1.3.2.min.js` if you are just starting you might consider using a more recent version of jQuery

Comment: Also it is unlikely you need to use any SESSION data, all you need to do is put `$_POST['textbox1']` back into the input field. Once you add a form of course

Comment: Hi, this is a sample form code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173182/add-remove-input-field-dynamically-with-jquery, not my actual form. For my form, there is another backend script which checks the form values and adds the form values into session variables and it works because the form fields which are not created dynamically using jquery are able to display its own session values. I was wondering is it because jquery is a front-end script but php is a back-end script, hence it doesn't display the session values?

Comment: I realised that it's because php is not able to read the value of the counter variable which is set in javascript. Just wondering is there any way to append the php session variables into the dynamic form fields, maybe through ajax?